# Where is my Great Answer badge?

Tags: support, badges

[This answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297037) hit 100 upvotes two days ago, but I haven't received a gold badge for it yet.  What gives?  Gold badges are all I have to live for, now that my goal of passing Jon Skeet is a wee bit out of reach.

And *do not* tell me "we don't need no steenking badges".

Comment: You did, but you're in debt. Don't fear the reaper.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1380/why-are-badges-sometimes-not-awarded

Comment: You want a badge for that answer -- apparently both reputation and badges are meaningless.

Comment: @tvanfosson: hey, the rules are the rules. Most Great Answer golds are dished out for some pretty unimpressive posts, IMHO.

Comment: @MusiGenesis there is no answer in the link. there is no question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I only see two +100 answers in your stats, and yet you have three "Great Answer" badges.  It seems likely that some of your previous "Great Answers" were migrated or deleted, and until you have more than three "live" +100 answers on the site, you aren't going to get another badge.

Sorry.  If it's any consolation, I am in the same boat with "Good Answer" and "Nice Answer", thanks to my (in)famous poll which was migrated here.

Comment: @Adam: two of my (current) golds are "populist", and two of the remaining 3 were for questions migrated to meta. I didn't see anything posted anywhere about golds not being awarded if you'd already received a gold for another different question that was removed. Now I'm stuck at 5? I can't even show my face on page 3.

Comment: I'm on page 2 with only one gold. (But I'm way ahead of you on silvers and bronzes.)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1380/why-are-badges-sometimes-not-awarded

Answer (score 8):

According to your [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14606/musigenesis) you have 3 `great answer` golds. However, looking at your answers, you have (now) 2 answers with 100+ net upvotes. Likely you had 2 other answers that had 100+ net upvotes, but they were on questions that have since been migrated here to meta ([Jon Skeet facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts/9151#9151) and [how to get over 200 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8086/how-to-get-over-200-reputation-points-every-day/8090#8090)). The system doesn't remove these badges when the question migrates, but the system does correct this as you "earn" more, you only earn replacements first, until you've replaced all the ones that were lost.

Jeff has stated this behavior [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10807/has-anybody-else-stopped-recieving-badges/10910#10910).

Comment: Is this principle actually stated anywhere?

Comment: @MusiGenesis: I can't find where Jeff described it, but yes it is, somewhere... Rest assured, yshuditelu and I are describing the situation truthfully and accurately.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1380/why-are-badges-sometimes-not-awarded

Comment: @Adam: I didn't mean to imply that you or yshuditelu were untruthful or inaccurate.