# Can an unearned 'good answer' badge that is block an earned one?

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, badges, up-votes

I've recently answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476550/c-any-standard-way-to-divide-a-class-into-regions/1476560#1476560) that has been **upvoted 25 times**.

A long time ago I got a silver good answer badge for an answer that must have been migrated, deleted or archived with question.  I've double checked [my account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30913/dove) history and I can see nice answer badge awarded this month but no good answer was.  I've had this silver badge for quite a while, the guts of a year I'd say.

Curious to know what may have happened.

**a**) My new good answer is taking place of archived one and so I don't warrant a second one, understandable behaviour if designed so.

**b**) Awarding of new badges is batched irregularly and it will be awarded in due course

**c**) This is an edge case bug and I should receive second silver good answer badge.

thanks.

Comment: a) This is a dupe. Searching...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work-in-stackoverflow/17854#17854

Comment: Found: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10807/has-anybody-else-stopped-recieving-badges

Comment: What does that question title mean

Comment: @John thanks, i did have a look but didn't hit on the right keywords

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The badge process kicks in regularly and every time it reports the number of badges of each type every user should *currently* have. If the count is larger than the count of badges you already have, you'll get a new badge. Otherwise, nothing will be awarded.

Answer (score 2):

It's **a)**.

Badge totals aren't recalculated, so if you lose one (question migration, question deletion, down-votes etc.) your total doesn't go down. Then the next one you win brings the total back to what it should be.

Comment: s/loose/lose/, otherwise +1

Comment: @Rich - I'm always making that mistake, cheers

Answer (score 2):

Since this question, badges have been overhauled and we look at a `ReasonId` column, which in this case is `Post.Id`.  If you don't have a badge *for that reason* (post in this case, tag, etc. in others) then you'll earn a new badge.

To be as accurate as possible, this isn't *always* the case.  Some are count based and have no reason, for example yearling does count years and see how many you need.