# no nice answer badge

Tags: bug, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Has anybody else stopped recieving badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10807/has-anybody-else-stopped-recieving-badges)

I recently posted an answer to a question. Neither the answer nor the question are CW. I got 18 upvotes and no downvotes, but I did not get the nice answer badge... Not that I absolutely need it like I'll start crying without it, but as a developer, you know... debug. Could be a non-running cron.

marking as bug, just because...

Comment: It might help if you post a link to the question/answer. Also the processes that allocate the badges run on a cycle so it might not have run yet

Comment: I know, but I don't want to appear as a no shame advertisement for my answer. Those who are interested in the problem, will fish it out easily.

Comment: It's presumably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039990 if anyone's interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/78374/stefano-borini) shows **Nice Answer x 22** badges with as many answers with **10+** upvotes.

Probably one of your other posts which generated a nice answer, got deleted / migrated / merged.

Badges are (almost) never removed, so you won't get the next (n) badges, because you already have "more" than you should.

That's by far the most common reason.

Comment: ah that's cool. Interesting! Thank you.

Comment: I forgot about that reason.