# no nice nor good answer badge

Tags: support, badges

I read 2 old posts [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35258/no-nice-answer-badge) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10807/has-anybody-else-stopped-recieving-badges), to try to understand why I didn't get this badge [for this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712550/how-i-can-debug-variable-in-django-on-web-page/18712582#18712582) too, like we can see [from that page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=1593705). What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Get them on what questions or answers exactly? Your highest voted answer got score of 4 and highest scored question got score of 1. (!)

Comment: You haven't been upvoted 10 times yet - read the badge description.

Comment: Score != reputation.

Comment: "Score" means number of upvotes, not amount of reputation earned - if that's what's confusing.

Comment: @RogerRowland ok I understood thank you

Comment: @RogerRowland: I thought the score was upvotes minus downvotes.

Comment: I respectfully submit that the down votes here might not be recognizing that "Score" and "Reputation" might not immediately seem like different things to new users.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Technically, you are correct there, as relates to the badge(s) in question.

Comment: @AndrewBarber in fact i was confused because "Answer score of 10 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times. " does not mean for me "get 10 upvote"; now I know :)

Comment: Oh, that old score-not-equal-to-rep chestnut. Why not just clarify the text, dagnammit?!

Comment: @GrantThomas i'd like to suggest such a text but i fear to be killed so I prefer that a moderator do it.

Comment: Because it rhymes @GrantThomas. "Answer score of 10 or more".... don't you dare touch it.

Comment: @Bart well, it can be changed to "Answer with 10 or more upvotes" but then it won't be accurate because answer with 15 upvotes and 6 downvotes won't give the badge. Back to square one!

Answer (score 4):

**Nice Question** Question score of 10 or more.
**Nice Answer** Answer score of 10 or more.

Score means `upvotes - downvotes = 10 upvotes` not 10 reputations.

Comment: As written, it sounds like you need exactly 0 downvotes. (When else would up - down = up?)

Comment: if you have atleast 10 upvotes more than the downvotes then **upvote - downvote =10**

Comment: I (and I expect others) understood what you meant; it was just a humorous algebra nitpick.  Still, though, it's `upvote - downvote ≥ 10`, not `update - downvote = 10`, since it's "score of 10 _or more_".